# call helper method from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, twilio

I would like to be able to click a button and send a text message to the person using twilio.

In my controller I have a helper method:
controllers/people_controller.rb:

```
  def send_text_message
        @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @account_sid = 'ACadb7a...bb88a3a69b6832'
    @auth_token = 'd751f77....645e31b72'

    # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)


    @account = @client.account
    @message = @account.sms.messages.create({
        :from => '+19526496571',
        :to => @person.phone,
        :body => "sent using twilio"
        })
  end

  helper_method :send_text_message
```

Then in the show view I would like to click the link and send the message:

`<%= link_to "message this user", {:action => controller.send_text_message}, {:method => :put } %>`

When I run this I get an error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in People#show

No route matches {:action=>"#<Twilio::REST::SMS::Message:0xb55a5658>", :id=>"2", :controller=>"people"}
```

How do I call the send_text_message method from the Person#show view?

Comment: Seems like you didn't add routes in routes.rb for your controller action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the **path** in the **routes.rb** file.

Something like:

```
put '/person/send_sms_message' => 'person#send_sms_message'
```